# Term::Readline unusual behavior

Tags: linux, perl, terminal, readline

I am creating the shell prompt using Term::Readline as given below -

```
my $expire_time = time + 25; # 25 sec timeout for testing and shared with thread
my $prompt   = 'SHELL> ';
my $terminal = Term::ReadLine->new('Shell Interface');
my $attribs  = $terminal->Attribs;
$terminal->ornaments(0);    # disable ornaments.

while ( defined( $_ = $terminal->readline($prompt) ) ) {
    if (/^\s*quit\s*$/xms) {
        # Cleanup the global parameters
        #...some cleanup code

        # Signal the thread to terminate, and then detach
        # it so that it will get cleaned up automatically
        # I will be using thread to control this customize shell
        $thread->kill('KILL')->detach();
        last;
        }
 }

 $thread = threads->create(
        sub {
            local $SIG{KILL} = sub { threads->exit() };
            eval {
                my $buffer_interval = int( sqrt( $expire_time - time() ) );
                my $term            = Term::ReadLine->new('Handle session of Shell');
                $term->ornaments(0);

                my $message = "Do you want to extend your session?[y/n]- ";
              INNER: while ( $expire_time > time() ) {

                    my $diff = $expire_time - time();
                    sleep 1;

                    print "diff - $diff, buffer_interval - $buffer_interval\n";

                    if ( $diff == $buffer_interval ) {

                        say "Your session will expire in $diff seconds due to inactivity.";
                        while ( defined( $_ = $term->readline($message) ) )
                        {
                            if (/^y$/i) {
                                $expire_time += $timeout;
                                say "refreshed expire_time - $expire_time";
                            }
                            next INNER;
                        }
                    }
                }
                &killproc('SHELL')
                  or die "cannot kill SHELL, aborting";
            };
        }
    );
```

This thread will handle the timeout of SHELL, $expire_time is set to some value say 90 seconds, the square root of timeout means 9 sec before user will be get the warning message that your session will be expire soon.. and if user will enter 'y' the session will be extended by $expire_time.

But when the Term::ReadLine object is created in thread , it is not behaving in the right way, sometime on entering 'y' the session extend and sometime not.

**Example is given below -**

expire time is - 1430279631
SHELL> diff - 25, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 24, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 23, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 22, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 21, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 20, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 19, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 18, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 17, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 16, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 15, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 14, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 13, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 12, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 11, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 10, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 9, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 8, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 7, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 6, buffer_interval - 5
diff - 5, buffer_interval - 5
Your session will expire in 5 seconds due to inactivity.
Do you want to extend your session?[y/n]- y
SHELL>

It is not printing the message inside while() loop saying that refreshing expire time...

Is this the problem because i am already in some Term::Readline prompt and again using the Term::Readline prompt inside one?

Is there any flushing problem?

Comment: You refer to `$thread` in the first while loop, but it is not yet defined.. is there some code missing from your example?

Comment: $thread is created using the threads->create() out of the while() loop.